# Session data not preserved after redirection

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement some custom flash messages and I'm having some issues with the session data being destroyed after a redirect.

Here's how I create my flash messages :

```
flash('Your topic has been created.');
```

Here's the declaration of the `flash()` function :

```
function flash($message, $title = 'Info', $type = 'info')
{   
    session()->flash('flash', [
        'message' => $message,
        'title' => $title,
        'type' => $type,        
    ]); 
}
```

And here is how I'm checking the session/displaying the flash messages, using SweetAlerts. This code is included at the bottom of the main layout file that I'm extending in all my Blade templates.

```
@if(Session::has('flash'))
    <script>
        $(function(){
            swal({
                title: '{{ Session::get("flash.title") }}',
                text : '{{ Session::get("flash.message") }}',
                type : '{{ Session::get("flash.type") }}',
                timer: 1500,
                showConfirmButton: false,           
            })
        });         
    </script>
@endif
```

The code above will work if I call the `flash()` function before displaying a view, like so :

```
public function show($slug)
{
    flash('It works!');
    return view('welcome');
}
```

However, it will not work if I call it before doing a redirect to another page, like so :

```
public function show($slug)
{
    flash('It does not work');
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Why is the session data lost on redirect? How can I make it persists so that I can display my flash message?

Comment: Could you please check urls before and after redirection? Sometimes you are on domain with `www.` and redirect to domain without `www.` and in this case you won't see session

Answer (score 12):

I found out that it is necessary to apply the web middleware on all routes. Drown has mentioned to do so, but since March 23st 2016, Taylor Otwell changed the default RouteServiceProvider at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/5c30c98db96459b4cc878d085490e4677b0b67ed

By that change the web middleware is applied automatically to all routes. If you now apply it again in your routes.php, you will see that `web` appears twice on the route list (`php artisan route:list`). This exactly makes the flash data discard.

Also see: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/session-flash-message-not-working-after-redirect-route/replies/159117

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that with Laravel 5.2, the routes have to be wrapped in the web middleware for the session to work properly.

This fixed it :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // ...
    Route::post('/topics/{slug}/answer', 'PostsController@answer');
    Route::post('/topics/{slug}/unanswer', 'PostsController@unanswer');
    Route::post('/topics/{slug}/delete', 'PostsController@delete');
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but this solution does not work for me.

Comment: @FlyingAtom Yes it was changed, but at the time when I asked the question you had to do it manually. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Please check APP/kernel.php

`\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`

is define multiple times

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
  ];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

You can comment any one or delete it. We need to define one time only.

Comment: YES!!!
Thank you!
Lots of different questions address this, but none of them solved it for me. This was exactly the problem. Both the middleware and the web group middleware had session start. Epic. 
Thanks!

Comment: that was the correct answer. thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The issue i had was `Session::save()` preventing swal from showing after redirect.

so you need to remove `Session::save()` or `session()->save();` from middleware

Comment: the issue is with `Session::save()` inside the middleware, please replace it.

Comment: @Harry Bosh, spending whole day to solve this until see your solution. It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With Laravel 5.2.34, all routes are using web middleware by default.

Therefore, change this:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { // This will use 2 web middleware

    // ...

    Route::post('/foo', 'FooController@foo');

});
```

To this:

```php
Route::group([], function () { // This will use the default web middleware

    // ...

    Route::post('/foo', 'FooController@foo');

});
```

And then in your controller you could use:

```php
class FooController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public foo() 
    {
        ...

        return redirect('/foo')->withSuccess('Success!!');
        // or
        return redirect('/foo')->with(['success' => 'Success!!']);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect with flash data is done like this:

```
redirect("/blog")->with(["message"=>"Success!"]);
```

In **early Laravel 5.2** versions, all of your `Flash` and `Session` data are stored only if your routes are inside `web middleware` group.

As of **Laravel 5.2.34**, all **routes are using web middleware by default**. If you will put them into middleware web group again, you will apply web middleware on your routes twice - such routes will be unable to preserve `Flash` or `Session` data.

Answer (score 1):

Check your App\Kernel.php file. 
There may be multiple lines of **\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,**
Comment one from $middlewareGroups.

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            **\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,**
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to **@Harry Bosh** answer,

In Laravel there an issue when `Session::save()` happen inside the middleware,
this make **_flash session gone after redirection** happen

this can be fix by using alternative :

```
// replace your Session::save() to this

session(['yoursessionvar' => $examplevar]); // this will save laravel session
```

Comment: I saved the variable in Session like this, but It doesn't work and wasn't the problem in my case. The problem was  StartSession middleware. It was added in $middlewareGroups[web] array, I removed it and add to $middleware array, as @rajesh said above.

Answer (score 0):

have you tired using "redirect with"

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was occurring, and I noticed that in `config/session.php` the `same_site` was set to 'none'. I am using Laravel 6. I changed that to null by checking the:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/6.x/config/session.php

I don't remember why i had changed it to 'none' but just changing that to 'null' fixed the problem. I have been struggling with it for a week now.

So if none of the above work, try this.