# Laravel Redirect->with(key, val) not working

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

I would like to send Informations from one function to an another with the `->with(key, val)` function, but it doesn't work. I've tried soo many things but it doesn't work.

Here my actual setup *(I'm using laravel 5.2)*:

### routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Route::get("/test1", "InfoController@test1");
    Route::get("/test2", "InfoController@test2");
});
```

### InfoController.php

```
class InfoController extends Controller
{
    public function test1(){
        return View::make("infos");
    }

    public function test2(){
        return Redirect::to("/test1")->with("hello", "world");
    }
}
```

### Infos.blade.php

```
{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get("hello")}}
```

The sit empty -> no output.

Where is the problem?

Comment: because `with()` flashes the data to the session [DOCS](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

Comment: When I use "{{session("hello")}}" I also get nothing back.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37496943/1897253

Comment: if your are use the latest version of 5.2.* try remove the web middleware

Comment: did you try {{ $hello }}?

Comment: @ABDEL-RHMAN Thank you!! Your are a hero! It's working.

Comment: @thmspl, really? Original `{{ $hello or 'Not defined' }}` worked for you after you removed `web` middleware?

Comment: If you find a solution to your question, please submit it as an **answer**. [Answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17851/209317) is very welcome at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with()` passes session data, not a variable. So you need to use session `get()` method to get the data:

```
{{ Session::get('hello') }}
```

Also, if you're using 5.2.27 or higher, [remove `web` middleware to make sessions work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784253/laravel-5-2-validation-error-not-appearing-in-blade).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But unfortunately it isn't working with "{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get("hello")}}"

Comment: Try just `{{ Session::get('hello') }}`, also if you're using latest 5.2 (5.2.27 and higher) try to remove `web` middleware from `routes.php`, because it applies automatically.

Comment: @thmspl You can use the `session('hello')` helper method. Or `session()->get('hello')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of `web` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
```

By default this middleware is applied for the entire application. So, calling it again just corrupts the flash and session data.

Comment: sorry, I did not read the hidden comments. The answer's author: feel free to open a new answer in order to OP to accept yours

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your answer!