# Laravel random drop session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I have a problem with random session drop.
The app is on nginx/php-fpm and session driver is redis.

When use: `return redirect()->away($url)` I have a problem, but when use `return view( 'template' )` (for test) all is OK. Drop is a about 10-20% traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving session before redirect,

```
$request->session()->save();
```

Also you should use away() when you want to 'redirect' to outside of your application such as another web site. You can use

```
redirect("url");
```

Comment: already use session()->save() before redirect. I tested with redirect("url"),  same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438852/session-data-not-preserved-after-redirection maybe this could help